# quick responses are prefered to polished words

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is natural in English?

1. In a casual talk, quick responses are prefered to polished words.
2. In a casual talk, it prefers a quick response to polished words.

I notice that 1) has alliteration ("*prefered to polished* words") and so it might sound better than 2). I am not sure.

Comment: The first one because 'it' does not refer to anything specific in the second sentence.

Comment: Thank you.         The structure is "In a casual talk, it..." - could "it" refer back to "a casual talk"?

Comment: 2 is not grammatical.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you be more detailed at the explaining? I've had a hard time to exclude the possibility of the legal use of a dummy "it" - It it is dummy, it doesn't need to be specific.

Comment: @NewPlanet You can't use the dummy it with the verb "prefers." Generally, dummy "it" is used with versions of to be. You could say something like "In a casual chat, it is fine to respond quickly instead of polishing your words."

Comment: Got it. That's an untold rule in English.  :)

Comment: would also eliminate "a" maybe, to apply the rhetoric to all casual talks and casual talk in general. Not just one specific or a casual talk. "In casual talk, quick responses are preferred to polished words."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have suggested in comments the first one is fine but

> In a casual talk, it prefers a quick response to polished words.

is not. The problem is that *it* refers back to *talk* but it is not the *talk* which is doing the preferring so it cannot be the subject of *prefers*.

You could have written

> In a casual talk, we prefer a quick response to polished words.
> In a casual talk, there is a preference for a quick response over polished words.